# Using variables included in another PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, scope

So I have a `config.php` file where I want to have login credentials.

**config.php**

```
<?php
  $server = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "admin123";
  $database = "web_apps";
  $table = "agencies";
?>
```

And I have a `connection.php` file in which the `config.php` file is included.

**connection.php**

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$connection = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Connection could not be established";
    exit();
}
$url_id = isset($_GET["id"])?$_GET["id"]:NULL;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table;
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$all_data =array();
$specific = array();
$name_list = array();
$fieldname = array();
$datatype = array();
$searchable = array();
$search_keys = array();
$name_keys = array();
$i = 0;
$m = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    if($i == 0){
        $fieldname = $row;
    }
    else if($i == 1){
        $datatype = $row;
    }
    else{
        $all_data[$row[0]]= $row;
        $name_keys[$m++] = $row[0];
    }
    $i++;
}
foreach ($all_data as $each_service){
    if(!strcmp($url_id, $each_service[0])){
        $specific = $each_service;
       break;
    }
}
for($i = 0; $i < count($datatype); $i++){
    if(strpos($datatype[$i], "search_")!== FALSE){
        $searchable[$i] = $datatype[$i];
        $search_keys[$i] = $i;
    }
}
$name_index = 0;
foreach ($datatype as $key) {
    if(strpos($key,"name") !== false){
        break;
    }
    $name_index++;
}

foreach ($all_data as $key=>$value) {
    $name_list[$key] = $value[$name_index];
}
//echo $name_index;
//print_r($names);
//var_dump($all_data);
//print_r($name_list);
//print_r($specific);
//print_r($fieldname);
//print_r($datatype);
//print_r($searchable);
//print_r($search_keys);
//print_r($name_keys);
$connection->close();
?>
```

The `connection.php` file is supposed to use the configuration variables in `config.php` and establish a connection to the database and throw out the data to other files. Both of these files are on the same directory. I have another file `index.php` which `requires_once` `connection.php` and displays the data in the application.

**index.php**

```
<?php require_once("core/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("core/header.php"); ?>

    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content main-content">
            <?php require_once('core/topbar.php'); ?>

            <select id="searchby">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Search by ... </option>
                <?php
                foreach($search_keys as $key){
                      echo "<option value=".$key.">".$fieldname[$key]."</option>";                    
                  }
                ?>
            </select>
            <form class="ui-filterable">
                <input id="autocomplete-input" data-type="search" placeholder=<?php echo '"Search by '.$fieldname[$search_category].'"'; ?>>
            </form>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-input="#autocomplete-input" data-inset="true">
                        <?php
                        if($search_category!=NULL){
                            $i = 0;
                            foreach ($all_data as $names){
                                echo "<li id='".$name_keys[$i]."'><a href='info.php?id=".$name_keys[$i++]."'>".$names[$search_category]." Name =  ".$names[$name_index]."</a></li>";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <img width="90%" src="img/cdcs-home.png" />
        </div>
<?php require_once("core/footer.php"); ?>
```

**problem**

The `connection.php` will show `var_dump` of data that is being pulled from the database. But the `index.php` wont't.
Whenever I open the index.php, it says :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: server in C:\xampp\htdocs\cdcs\core\connection.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined variable: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\cdcs\core\connection.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined variable: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\cdcs\core\connection.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined variable: database in C:\xampp\htdocs\cdcs\core\connection.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined variable: table in C:\xampp\htdocs\cdcs\core\connection.php on line 10

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\cdcs\core\connection.php on line 12
```

If I declare and initialize all the config variables inside `connection.php`, index.php shows the data in the application.

I want to have 3 files as it is and still show the information `index.php` from the database configured in `config.php` via `connection.php`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does the code for index.php look like ? Can you also post the full code for your connection.php file? Possibly there are other parts of the code that might be causing the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to post the code for index.php and connection.php and/or anything else that might be relevant.

Comment: Are you sure that a valid database connection is getting created in connection.php? Which is the file that is giving you error. Corresponding error line nos. maybe ?

Comment: yes @Maximus2012 The index.php says that I have problem in connection.php. But the connection.php wont give error by itself. I will load and show the data if i var dump in it.

Comment: what does var_dump($connection) in connection.php give you? Right after you create a connection.

Comment: In `connection.php` you only close the php tag but never open it. As you include `config.php` you don't need to close php in that file.

Comment: object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: f373ea5dd5538761406a8022a4b8a374418b240e $" ["client_version"]=> int(50011) [" ....

Comment: it was missing when I copied my code here @SuperDJ. That should not be the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are executing the `index.php` which is located in `C:\xampp\htdocs\cdcs\`.

There you are executing `require_once 'core/connection.php'` which will *include* that scripts content into your index.php. Therefore any code within the file `connection.php` now runs from the same directory, `index.php` is located.

Therefore it cannot find `config.php` and fails to include, and therefore your variables are undefined. The script looks for `C:\xampp\htdocs\cdcs\config.php` rather than `C:\xampp\htdocs\cdcs\core\config.php`

To fix this, use `require_once 'core/config.php'` inside your `connection.php` or setup a proper usage of the `include-dir` within your php.ini.

Sidenode: You should use `Constants` instead of `variables` because variables are used for changing content, which your database credentials usually don't do during execution time.

Comment: I think that seems to be the case here.